# I only get this in production: NoReverseMatch: Reverse for...with arguments...and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I've been fighting with this error for a while and I need some help. It's only happening on my production server. Locally I can run my application without any issues.

I'm getting the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'location_cert_uploads' with arguments '(u'101589',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Here's my code
(urls.py)

```
... url(r'^location/(?P<location_id>\d+)/certificates/$', 'locations.views.cert_uploads', name='location_cert_uploads')....
```

(views.py)

```
def cert_uploads(request, location_id):  # aka uploads
...
...
return render_to_response('locations/location_certificates.html', variables, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

note: in my views.py I do have two spots with this line of code:

```
return redirect("{0}?id={1}&page={2}".format(reverse('location_cert_uploads', args=[location_id]), str(obj.id), page))
```

(my html page):

```
<a href="{% url 'location_cert_uploads' location.id %}" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Certificates"><i class="fa fa-file fa-lg"></i></a>
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your URLs regex, `location_id` is a named group (the `(?P<name>expression)` part of the regex). This translates to a kwarg (keyword argument) with the same name in your view function.

Since `location_id` is a kwarg, you need to pass it as a kwarg to the url tag: `{% url 'location_cert_uploads' location_id=location.id %}`

Comment: I just gave it a shot, and still got the error: django.core.urlresolvers in _reverse_with_prefix

any other thoughts or information i can provide?

Comment: Just a side now, when I try and call the reserve command in the shell (from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse)

I get this:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 12, in <module>
    from importlib import import_module
ImportError: No module named importlib

Could this be part of the issue?